# how to make a javascript library working in node js for server side operations

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, module

I am trying to create a library for a project, its like this:

```
module.exports = Diary;
function Diary() {

    someFunction = function( message ) {
        console.log(message)
    }

    function D() {
        return new D._Section;
    }

    D.about = {
        version: 1.0
    };

    D.toString = function () {
        return  "Diary "+ D.about.version;
    };

    var Section = function () {
        this.Pages = []
    }

    D._Section = Section;

    //to extend the library for plugins usage
    D.fn = sectionproto = Section.prototype = D.prototype;

    sectionproto.addPage = function (data) {
        this.Pages.push(data)
        conole.log(this.Pages)
    };
    return D;
};
```

main purpose for this is to use same library for server side and client side operations, so we can have same code base.

this issue is that when i use this in node app

```
var Diary = require('./diary.js');
var myDiary = new Diary();

console.log(myDiary.addPage('some text on page'))
```

and run it, it throws an error
    TypeError: myDiary.addPage is not a function

i am not not sure what to do here to make this work for node js, as our client app is very huge and making changes to it would require some effort if we have to go in some other pattern.

First Question is:
 1. is this approach right or we need to look in to something else
 2. if this can work on node js app then how with minimum changes to library

Comment: That's **really** convoluted. What's the reason for all the seemingly-unnecessary layers?

Comment: i copied the structure from Raphaeljs as i need some layers for this application and yes i am trying to learn Javascript and Nodejs @JasonSebring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're exporting your overall `Diary` function, but then *using* it as though you'd received its return value (the `D` function) instead.

The way you're exporting it, you'd use it like this:

```
var Diary = require('./diary.js')();
// Note -------------------------^^
var myDiary = new Diary();
```

But beware that that means **every** import will create its own `D` function and associated things.

Alternately, export the result of calling `Diary`, but then the `Diary` function has no purpose.

---

*Other* issues are:

- You're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)* by not declaring `someFunction` or `sectionproto`. Be sure to declare your variables.
- The structure is over-complicated without any obvious reason it needs to be so complicated.

* *(disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: thanks for answer it helped and code is working with it. sure will cover those global declarations.